# How to declare and manipulate an array of Strings in 8086 assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am working in emu8086 version 4.08. I have to make a student database. So, if I want to store a list of names or ID in an array of strings how can I do it? or is there any other way? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
include 'emu8086.inc' 

.model small
.stack 100h  


.data  


  str2 dw 20 dup('$')

.code   

  mov ax,@data
  mov ds,ax

main proc



  mov si,0





  mov str2[si],"student1$"
  add si,1  

  mov str2[si],"student2$"
  add si,1

  mov str2[si],"student3$"
  add si,1

  mov str2[si],"student4$"



mov ah,4ch 
int 21h               

endp main 


DEFINE_SCAN_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_STRING
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS  
DEFINE_PTHIS
```

Comment: How would you go about storing grades in an array of numbers? Think about this and see if it sets you in the right direction. Anyhow, you should include some programming code in your question so we can appreciate what you know or don't know.

Comment: @SepRoland I edited the post and added the code. while emulating it says, "cannot convert to 16 bit value: "student1$" " and same for all the strings.

Comment: Can you add to your question what your homework assignment actually is. From the code it's not entirely clear what the parameters of the question really are. But as it stands things like `mov str2[si],"student1$"` won't work. You don't move strings with `mov`, but you can move the addresses of strings.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> mov str2[si],"student1$"
> ```

You're wrong in what SI stands for. You think that it is an index in the array, but is is not. In assembly language it is an offset in memory (measured in bytes).

The string "student1$" has **9** characters and so you must provide room to store all of those characters, 1 byte per character. Furthermore you can't assign the complete string in one go. You'll have to use a loop for that.

---

First change the definition of the array and store the name in a tempory location:

```
str2 db 4*10 dup(0)
sname db "student1$"
```

This will give room for storing 4 student names of 9 characters plus an extra terminating character (if wanted).

---

Next use a loop to write a student name:

```
 mov di, offset str2
 mov si, offset sname
More:
 mov al, [si]
 mov [di], al
 inc si
 inc di
 cmp al, "$"
 jne More
```

---

For the next student the name will have to be written to **str2 + 10**

Comment: I believe that `name` is an emu8086 reserved word. You might want to rename it to `sname` (student name). As well, given that emu8086 is similar to _MASM_ syntax  these 2 lines won't work: `mov di, str2` `mov si, name` as they both attempt to retrieve what is AT memory address of `str2` and `name` and not the addresses themselves. You'll want the offset of the labels so it should be `mov di, offset str2` `mov si, offset sname` . I think emu8086 requires your array definition to be something like `str2  db 4 * 10 dup(0)`

Comment: You're right. It's been a while that I've used emu8086 on account of it being so quirky.